# Space is Banach if space of bounded sequences is Banach

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show the following:

> Let $X$ be a normed linear space and
>
> $$b(X) = \{ (x_n)_{n \geq 1} : x_n \in X\ \forall n \geq 1, \ \|
> (x_n)_{n \geq 1} \|_\ast := \sup_{n \geq 1} \| x_n \| < \infty \}.$$
>
> Show: If $b(X)$ is a Banach space, then $X$ is a Banach space.

What I was able to do is the following: Maybe it is a good idea to show: "If $X$ is not a Banach space, then $b(X)$ is not a Banach space." So if we assume that $X$ is not a Banach space, there exists a Cauchy-sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ in $X$ which is divergent. Since Cauchy-sequences are bounded, this divergent sequence is an element of $b(X)$. Now we have to show that there exists a divergent Cauchy-sequence in $b(X)$ (with using our converging sequence), but I am really struggling with this since we have to look at sequences of sequences. How could one solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $x \to (x,x,...)$ is an isometric isomorphism from $X$  into $b(X)$ so we only have to verify that the range is closed. If $(x_n,,x_n,...) \to (y_1,y_2,...)$ in $b(X)$ then $x_n \to y_j$ for every $j$ so $y_j$ is independent of $j$. Call it $y$. We also have $x_n \to y$. Thus the range is closed.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to find a closed copy of $X$ inside of $b(X)$. My favourite is the subspace $V \subset b(X)$ of all constant sequences. That means sequences of the form $(x,x,\ldots)$ for $x \in X$. It's an exercise to prove $V$ is closed in $b(X)$. Hence if $b(X)$ is complete so is $V$ and hence $X$.